# How to get Jenkins version metrics information in Prometheus?

Tags: jenkins, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator

I have some Jenkins instances deployed in K8s Cluster. Currently, I am able to scrape/fetch Jenkins metrics/logs inside Prometheus, Grafana. But now my purpose is to see if all Jenkins instances have the same version or not. I did not find any query in Grafana to scrape **Jenkins's **version** metrics**. However, I can see the metrics such as CPU usage, memory usage, Jenkins uptime (default_jenkins_uptime), etc. Is there any expert who has the same issue? Thanks in Advance, stay safe

[image]

Comment: I think it is irrelevant to the elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jenkins Prometheus plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/prometheus-plugin) only exposes metrics defined in the [Metrics plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/metrics-plugin):

> Currently only metrics from the Metrics-plugin and summary of build duration of jobs and pipeline stages

The version is not part of the informations exposed and it would have to build an `info` metric for that.

You won't be able to get it unless there is development in the plugin to implement the feature.